# Turning Ethernet port LED off in Linux

Tags: linux, hardware, ethernet

In linux I'm using "ip link" command to turn DOWN specific ethernet port on my PC.
When doing this the port LED turn off for a bit then turn again ON (but the connection is still DOWN if I check with "ip link").

Is there a way to keep the LED off when network link is DOWN?

> ip a

```
4: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:1a:9f:81:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp3s0
```

> ethtool eno1

```
Settings for eno1:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
                                2500baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
                                2500baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        MDI-X: off (auto)
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: no
```

> ethtool -i eno1

```
driver: igc
version: 6.5.5-zen1-1-zen
firmware-version: 1073:8754
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:03:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

Comment: usually, these LEDs are hard-wired to the PHY or MAC layer hardware. Only if that hardware has a register that says "ignore your internal state, turn off LED" you can do that.

Comment: Found this [post](https://pwmon.org/p/1900/quest-disable-lan-leds-intel-nuc/) Do you think can be adattable to any pc or is just an Intel nuc feature?

Comment: totally different ethernet hardware, so that tells us nothing about the ability of *your* system to do that. It's not a feature of the NUC, it's a feature of the network interface hardware used in there.